# How to configure HalfExpanded value in ModalBottomSheetLayout - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

I want to show only 30% of my sheet instead of 50% in `HalfExpanded` state of `ModalBottomSheetLayout`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the HalfExpanded state by passing a `Modifier` to the `ModalBottomSheetLayout` that defines the desired height of the sheet in that state.

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    state = state,
    sheetContent = { /* content */ },
    sheetPeekHeight = Modifier.preferredHeight(height)
)
```

`height` in dp (You can calculate 30% of height from screen height)

Comment: You cannot set sheetPeekHeight for ModalBottomSheetLayout. It can be set only for BottomSheetScaffold. But in BottomSheetScaffold I cannot have a Hidden state too. I need 3 states like in ModalBottomSheetLayout but instead of fixed HalfExpanded I need it to be customizable.